# How to convert a for loop to function in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, data-manipulation

I am trying to convert for loop to function for the group summary statistics based on the `c("country", "continent")`.  Any help would be appreciated, many thanks in advance.

```
library(gapminder)
library(purr)
cont <- unique(gapminder$continent)
df <- NULL
temp <- NULL
for(i in 1:(length(cont))) {
  temp <- gapminder[gapminder$continent == cont[i], ]
  #df[[i]] <- temp
  df[[i]] <- temp %>% split(.$continent) %>% map(summary)
  
}
df
```

Expected Answer

```
my.function(gapminder, c("country", "continent"))
```

Comment: Is your for loop correct?  It doesn't mention country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a `dplyr` and `purrr` solution?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gapminder %>% 
  group_by(country, continent) %>% 
  group_split(.keep = TRUE) %>% 
  map(summary)
```